# Explain 2-D array using pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to run the following code and getting "gh" as the output. Please help me out, how are we getting this result.

```
void f(char **p) {
    char *t;
    t = (p += sizeof(int))[-1];
    printf("%s\n", t);
}

int main() { 
    char *arg[] = { "ab", "cd", "ef", "gh", "ij", "kl" };
    f(arg);
}
```

P.S. I am using the gcc compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p+=sizeof(int)` will make `p` to point `sizeof(int)` elements farther from the 0<sup>th</sup> element so that `p+=sizeof(int)` will give the address of the 4<sup>th</sup> element of passed array (assuming size of `int` 4 bytes on your machine). `[-1]` will decrement it by one letting `t` to point to the 3<sup>rd</sup> element which is `"gh"`.

Comment: *p+=sizeof(int) will add  sizeof(int) bytes to p*: Not really, it will make `p` point `sizeof(int)` elements farther. `p` is a `char **`, so the elements are `char*`. The rest of your explanation is correct.

Comment: @chqrlie; I need some rest for today.